# How can I flip multiple div at same time?

Tags: html, css, flip

How can I flip multiple div at same time when I click the button? It works well when it only has one div. But how can I make multiple objects flip at same time? I try to change #flip-toggle to class .flip-toggle , but it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:
CSS:

```
        .flip-container {
            -webkit-perspective: 1000;
            -moz-perspective: 1000;
            perspective: 1000;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper, .flip-toggle.flip .flipper {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        .flip-container, .front, .back {
            width: 160px;
            height: 160px;
        }

        .flipper {
            -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -moz-transition: 0.6s;
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: 0.6s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            position: relative;
        }

        .front, .back {
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .front {
            background: lightgreen;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .back {
            background: lightblue;
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

    </style>

Html:
<body>
   <div class="flip-container flip-toggle">
    <div class="flipper">
       <div class="front">
        <img src="image01.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="back">               
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-container flip-toggle">
    <div class="flipper">
       <div class="front">
        <img src="image02.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="back">   

       </div>
    </div>
    </div>

   <button onclick="document.querySelector('.flip-toggle').classList.toggle('flip');" >Toggle Flip</button>
</body>
```

Comment: According to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector querySelector only returns the first matching element.  Is JQuery out of the question?  There is also a querySelectorAll, but you would have to iterate the returned elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing on using jQuery then i would suggest you to have a look on the [QuickFlip 2](http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin)

If not i've got a simple answer here for you.

Wrap both divs into a parent one and make the parent one flip on the button click.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BwGu4/) for you.

You will still need to make some changes as once you flip the parent div the child divs doesn't flip anymore until you flip the parent again, but this can be fixed easily.

```
<div class="flip-toggle">
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <img src="image01.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <img src="image02.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.flip-toggle').classList.toggle('flip');">Toggle Flip</button>
```

Comment: Cheers, glad i could help :)
If that was the answer you were looking for can i ask you to mark my answer as the accepted answer? Thanks